# Php MySql white page

Tags: php, mysql

I just tried to make a simple thing in php and i failed terribly don't know why.
This is my code:

```
<?php

$db_dbname = "name1";
$db_hostname = "hostname";
$db_username = "lol";
$db_password = "thisismypassword";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$db_dbname.';host='.$db_hostname.'', $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$obterdados = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC");
$obterdados->execute();
$data= $obterdados->fetchAll();

 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }

?>
```

after that, when i open the page, no code (html) bellow is executed and the page is all white.
If i remove the :

```
$obterdados = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC");
$obterdados->execute();
$data= $obterdados->fetchAll();
```

it works normaly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `$conn` for your connection and `$dbh` for your query.

Error reporting would have thrown you an undefined dbh notice.

That is why the first one did not throw you anything, up to the point you started querying.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroBarbosa Glad to hear it. Cheers